# What is the difference between axis and axes in FlotJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I'm confused using [Flot Charts](https://www.flotcharts.org/), it appears that Axes and Axes share the same options between them

Can someone explain me the difference between Axis and Axes?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Axes (as in `xaxes` or `yaxes`) is an array of axis objects for charts where you use multiple x-axes or multiple y-axis. In general `xaxis` represents `xaxes[0]`.